# Recursion_Count of aaa

Tags: java, string, recursion, substring

Write a recursive function which counts, the number of times “aaa”
appears in the string. Print the value returned.

Input:
aaaaaa

output:
4

wrote the below code using recursion but the value of "a" is not getting updated and also the compiler can't find the symbol "count". Can anyone point to the error in the code below:

```
public static int retcount(String st,int s,int e){
        if(e>st.length()-1){
          return count;
        }
         int count=0;
        if(st.contains(st.substring(s,e))){
              count=count+1;
            retcount(st,s+1,e+1);
        }
         return count;
        }
```

Comment: You need to declare count like `int count` .  And you probably need it to work for something like `"aaxxaaaaakskskaakskskaaa"` which would be 4.

Comment: I did initialize count in line no 5 as 0 but it is not getting updated it seems.

Comment: But you reference it prior to that.   And why are you passing `start` and `end` when you just need to find a three character string.  And a string will always contains a substring of itself.  You need to check if the current substring is equal to "aaa".

Comment: BTW, is this homework?

Comment: And please take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 1):

Here are some ideas that might help. Consider a starting string of `"abcdefgh"`.

1. if I call the method with substring(1).  I will get `"bcdefgh"`
2. if I do it again I will get `"cdefgh"`.
3. At some point you want to be able to see if a passed string starts with "aaa".  Each time you just need to see if `st.substring(0,3) equals "aaa"`
4. if so, I want to increment the count and return the value.
5. otherwise, I don't increment the count and return the value.
6. Since the calls are unwinding, the string will build back up, one character at a time.  So repeat the above process starting with (3).

Use print statements in the method to help determine what is going on.

Eventually, you can pass a string and a desired `target substring` as arguments. You can use the `length` of the `target` to adjust for substring matching.

Comment: Nice method, except that I couldn't understand point (6) well. (a) What is "unwinding"? (b) If we simply have a loop starting `0` to `(length of target) - (length of substring)`, it will cover everything, isn't it? Then why restart from `3`?

Comment: @SreeKumar It is a term that I and others have used to describe the return process of getting the values off the call stack.  As the method calls itself, the current state of the variables are stored on the call stack.  As you return from those calls,  the previous state from those calls is returned in reverse order.  So it's like unwinding something that has been wound.  Next time I answer a similar question I will skip the metaphor.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example.

```java
int count(String a, String b, int x) {
    if (a.contains(b)) x = count(a.substring(1), b, ++x);
    return x;
}
```